# Редактор текста для React.js без вложенных тегов

Tags: javascript, reactjs, telegram-bot, telegram, edittext

Делаю поле для рассылки сообщений через телеграм-бота, и нужно дать пользователю без знаний html возможность модивицировать текст.

Ищу библиотеку/компонент редактора текста, самый простой (для тегов b, u, s, code, pre, i), т.к. телеграм больше не поддерживает.

Но гланая задача - редактор не должен допускать вложенности тегов. Telegram это запрещает.

Кто-то знает подобные библиотеки? Или как такое можно быстро реализовать.

Comment: Библиотек куча, но если мне не изменяет память, то они сразу любой текст кладут в тег ```<p>{{ TEXT }}<\p>```. То получается, весь ваш текст уже будет обернут тегом и тогда получается, что у вас будут вложенные теги.

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев уже использовал такие, знаю как работают. По этому ищу вот такие специфичиские.

Comment: ну тогда либо самим писать, либо удалять все теги <p>.

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев удалить можно, а что делать с вложенными? к примеру <b><i></i></b>